# Avoid FloodWait in python

Tags: python, error-handling, telegram, pyrogram

I am new to Pyrogram and I try to make subsctiption bot

I want to send messages as soon as any satisfy my filters, but every time I send more than 3 messages in a row I get FloodWait error. There is no problem in catching that exception, but it is always getting bigger

15 -> 60 -> 333 -> 417 seconds

How can I avoid it? Sleeping for some seconds after every message doesn't help. And I didn't find anything about exact estimated waiting time in docs

```py
            for user in subs_arr:
                try:
                    app.send_message(user, msg)
                    time.sleep(10)
                except pyrogram.errors.exceptions.flood_420.FloodWait as wait_err:
                    wait_err = str(wait_err)
                    time.sleep(wait_err.x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that there is no way to avoid FloodWait  :D

But I had totally wrong understanding of time.sleep. I used Pyrogram for that bot, bot I didn't need async component of that
Nevertheless bot requires asynchronous sleep and I had problems with reworking it  this way. Finally I came up with that solution (now sleep usually is <=60 second)

```py
try:
     await app.send_message(user, msg)
     await asyncio.sleep(3)
except pyrogram.errors.exceptions.flood_420.FloodWait as wait_err:
     await asyncio.sleep(wait_err.x)
except TimeoutError:
     continue
except pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.UsernameNotOccupied:
                    continue
```

Hope it'll help somebody or even somebody will advice me better way of doing this

Comment: set `wait_err.value`, not `wait_err.x`.